# Pyinstaller - .ico file still not included from .spec (--onefile)

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to use pyinstaller to make an .exe for my Python program. I altered the datas the .spec file so that it would include my program's .ico file, but it still says it is missing the .ico on execution.

The spec file (Raven.py is my program and raven.ico is the .ico file it needs):

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['C:\\Users\\Andrew\\Desktop\\project\\Raven.py'],
         pathex=['C:\\Users\\Andrew'],
         binaries=None,
         datas=[ ('C:\\Users\\Andrew\\Desktop\\project\\raven.ico', '.') ],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
         a.scripts,
         a.binaries,
         a.zipfiles,
         a.datas,
         name='Raven',
         debug=False,
         strip=False,
         upx=True,
         console=True )
```

This is what I am typing into the command prompt for pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller --onefile C:\Users\Andrew\Raven.spec
```

Then it acts like its working and creates the .exe file, which says it is missing raven.ico and terminates.

Adding the .ico file to the same directory as the .exe makes the program work perfectly fine.

Also, if it matters, I am using Tkinter and Raven.py imports two other python files of mine.

Comment: Try providing the .ico file with `-i` parameter.

Comment: In the exe block add a line that says `icon='C:\\Users\\Andrew\\Desktop\\project\\raven.ico',`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add the option icon in your spec. If you want to add

> 'C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\project\raven.ico'

you should use

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['C:\\Users\\Andrew\\Desktop\\project\\Raven.py'],
     pathex=['C:\\Users\\Andrew'],
     binaries=None,
     datas=[ ('C:\\Users\\Andrew\\Desktop\\project\\raven.ico', '.') ],
     hiddenimports=[],
     hookspath=[],
     runtime_hooks=[],
     excludes=[],
     win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
     win_private_assemblies=False,
     cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
     cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
     a.scripts,
     a.binaries,
     a.zipfiles,
     a.datas,
     name='Raven',
     debug=False,
     strip=False,
     upx=True,
     console=True , icon='C:\\Users\\Andrew\\Desktop\\project\\raven.ico')
```